# convert function to use css translate3d

Tags: javascript, css

I've written a function in Javascript to make images draggable within a container. Even if the image is enlarged it can be dragged all over the screen without disappearing from it. My function relies heaving on using style.top and style.left. Now I've heard that using translate3d might provide better performance. This is interesting because I changed my image scale function, which uses a slider, to scale3d and the scaling is clearly smoother, no doubt. So could anyone help me convert this function I've written to use translate3d? I've tried and tried but have kept failing. Many Thanks:

EDIT:  I put up a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/bx4073tr/

Please note that imgRect is the parent div while img is the image itself (it's in an img tag contained in the div).

```
function makeImageDraggable(event) {
    // Make an image draggable but within bounds of container
    let overflow_vertical = false;
    let overflow_horizontal = false;
    // bounding rectangles to hold image and imageContainer
    let imgRect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    let imgContainerRect = imageContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
    // find out if image overflows it's container div
    // check for vertical overflow, getBoundingClientRect().height will get the real height after the image is scaled
    if ( imgRect.height > imageContainer.offsetHeight ) {
        overflow_vertical = true;
    }
    // check for horizontal overflow
    if ( imgRect.width > imageContainer.offsetWidth ) {
        overflow_horizontal = true;
    }
    // if there is no overflow, either horizontal or vertical, then do absolutely nothing
    if (!overflow_horizontal && !overflow_vertical) {
        // nothing to do
    } else {
        // otherwise make image draggable
        event = event || window.event;
        // get initial mouse position
        let startX = event.clientX;
        let startY = event.clientY;

        // get position of image to be dragged
        let offsetX = pixelToFloat(img.style.left);
        let offsetY = pixelToFloat(img.style.top);

        // add onmousemove event now we are sure user has initiated a mousedown event
        window.onmousemove = function(mousemove_event) {
            if (mousemove_event == null) {
                mousemove_event = window.event;
            }
            // calculate bounds so that image does not go off the page
            // if there is an overflow, the image will be bigger than the container
            // so we need to find the maximum distance we can go upwards, downwards and sideways
            // using img.getBoundingClientRect, we can get the width of the scaled image, we also get the width of the container
            // divide it by 2 so we can move the same number of pixels in either direction
            // max right and left
            let max_right = -1 * ( ((imgRect.right - imgRect.left) - (imgContainerRect.right - imgContainerRect.left))/2 );
            // should be a positive number
            let max_left = -1 * (max_right);
            // max bottom and top
            let max_bottom = -1 * ( ((imgRect.bottom - imgRect.top) - (imgContainerRect.bottom - imgContainerRect.top))/2 );
            // should be a positive number
            let max_top = -1 * (max_bottom);
            // Dragging image left and right 
            if (!overflow_horizontal) {
            } else {
                let scrollX = (offsetX + mousemove_event.clientX - startX);
                // img.style.left will keep increasing or decreasing, check if it approaches max_left or max_right
                if (scrollX >= max_left || scrollX <= max_right) {
                    //return false;imageContainer.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + newX + 'px,' + newY + 'px, 0)';
                } else {
                    if (scrollX < max_left) { img.style.left = min(scrollX, max_left) + 'px'; }
                    if (scrollX > max_right) { img.style.left = max(scrollX, max_right) + 'px'; }
                }
            }
            // Dragging image top to bottom
            if (!overflow_vertical) {
            } else {
                let scrollY = (offsetY + mousemove_event.clientY - startY);
                // as an expanded image is pulled downwards, img.style.top keeps increasing to approach max_top
                // if it reaches max top, simply do nothing, else keep increasing
                // check for both conditions, approaching max_top and approaching max_bottom
                if (scrollY >= max_top || scrollY <= max_bottom) {
                   // return false;
                } else {
                    if (scrollY < max_top) { img.style.top = min(scrollY, max_top) + 'px'; }
                    if (scrollY > max_bottom) { img.style.top = max(scrollY, max_bottom) + 'px'; }
                }
            }
            // return
            return false;
        } 
    }

    // cancel mousemove event on mouseup
    window.onmouseup = function(mouseup_event) {
        window.onmousemove = null;
        // Should not return false as it will interfere with range slider
    }
    // return false
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried replacing all instances of img.style.top and img.style.left with img.style.transform = 'translate3d(scrollXpx, scrollYpx, 0) scale(currentScale)' and the image jumps all over the place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works now. 
See makeDraggable method in the fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/daibatzu/0u74faz6/6/

All you have to do is add this function to the event listener for the image like:
var img = document.getElementById('myImage');
img.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) { makeDraggable(event); });

Code

```
function makeDraggable(event) {
    // get bounding rectangle
    let imgRect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    let parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
    // check overflow
    let overflow_horizontal = (imgRect.width > parent.offsetWidth ? true : false);
    let overflow_vertical = (imgRect.height > parent.offsetHeight ? true : false);
    // get start position
    let startX = event.pageX - translateX, startY = event.pageY - translateY;
    let max_left = parentRect.left - imgRect.left;
    let max_top = parentRect.top - imgRect.top;
    window.onmousemove = function(evt) {
        // set event object
        if (evt == null) { evt = window.event; }
        // Say max_left is 160px, this means we can only translate from 160px to -160px to keep the image visible
        // so we check if the image moves beyond abs(160), if it does, set it to 160 or -160 depending on direction, else, let it continue
        translateX = (Math.abs(evt.pageX - startX) >= max_left ? (max_left * Math.sign(evt.pageX - startX)) : (evt.pageX - startX));
        translateY = (Math.abs(evt.pageY - startY) >= max_top ? (max_top * Math.sign(evt.pageY - startY)) : (evt.pageY - startY));
        // check if scaled image width is greater than it's container. if it isn't set translateX to zero and so on
        translateX = overflow_horizontal ? translateX : 0, translateY = overflow_vertical ? translateY : 0;
        // translate parent div
        parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(' + translateX + 'px, ' + translateY + 'px)';
        // return
        return false;
   }
    window.onmouseup = function(evt) {
        // set mousemove event to null
        window.onmousemove = null;
    }
    return false;
 };
```